# How can I prepare for PM interview?

Tags: interviewing

For software development position I was interviewing, I passed technical interview. Next step is project manager interview. All this interview is done on phone because job is at another country. I know that I missed different opportunities because I fail this part of interviews. Technical part is piece of cake but this kind of interview is my soft spot. How can I prepare this interview ?

Answer (score 3):

I have went through a lot of Telephonic interviews in past couple of years. This is how I can summarize for you -

1. Technical Interviews i.e. 1st Phase is focused on your technical skills which can go from Beginner level to More Advanced Level. So, if you are good with your technical, its easy to crack.
2. PM Level Interviews i.e. 2nd Phase is more focused on your work experience. They will ask you about the Projects you have been involved into, personal questions and scenario based questions to test your decision making skills.

The big difference here is, PM doesn't care a lot about your coding skills (speaking about the software dev interviews), they will be verifying your decision making skills and how you react to the situations. He will check your behavior, appearance(in case of Video Calls), your family background etc. He will ask you about your future goals and how you are going to achieve it.

*Preparing -

1. Be yourself. Speak Truth. Do not panic.
2. If you are unsure about an answer, go ahead and ask for the optimal solution from his perspective. That leaves a good touch.
3. Be a gentleman. Greet well.
4. Make sure you prepare questions like "Where do you see yourselves after X years?"

Last advice will be - Also, there is a fine line between confidence and over-confidence. Make sure you don't sound the later one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `Be a gentleman.`  Umm, some of us aren't gentlemen, and the OP hasn't specified their gender ;)  You could just say "Be polite and greet well."

Comment: Family background??

Comment: @BSC I didn't understand second entry. Something like "What will you do for this situation ?"

Comment: @waystand Its about how you deal with a specific situation. For example, "You have a limited time to deliver the product to the customer. Will you focus on Quality of code or will to you go with Quick and Dirty method?" I hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prepare for PM interview?

Other than your statement that you "fail this part of interviews" we have no way to know *why* you failed, so can't give you much useful advice here.

If you have a project manager in your personal network, you may want to work with her/him and do some practice interviews. Have your friend ask you some of the questions that might normally be asked in an interview. Then, you answer as you usually would, and your project manager friend critiques your answers.

Other than that, just study and be as prepared as you can on the company and the markets they serve.